# How to fix request input alpha character from multiple checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

You guys who know this, please tell me more why when I asked for two checkboxes or more than one it will get error 403 forbidden? But if I sent it with one checkbox, it worked

> error request with multiple checkboxes alpha character https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ0Qh.jpgYou

this is my ajax request

```
               $('.btntambah').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data =  []; 
                var arr = $('input[name="available"]:checked').map(function () {
                    data.push($(this).val());
                }).get();
                if (data[0] == 'on') {
                    data.shift();

                }
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(data);
                $.post("/locarea",{data : data}, function(response){
                    console.log(response);

                });

        });
```

Bellow is function controller

```
public function store(Request $request){return $request->all();}
```

Then my request input array success if test using numeric character via postman

> please check postman https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9oNO.png

why when I try request input alpha character cannot return data ? just forbidden error 403

thank your for attention

Comment: Please paste your HTML code of checkboxes.

Comment: @akshaypjoshi <input type="checkbox" id="available" name="available" onclick="toggle(this,'available')"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

HTML:

```
<form id="theForm" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="available[]" value="Wing A" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="available[]" value="Wing B" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="available[]" value="Wing C" />
</form>
```

Ànd in your JS:

```
$('.btntambah').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.post("/locarea",{data : $('#theForm').serialize()}, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Laravel recieves an array named "available", where you will find your data in.
Give it a try.

EDIT: 
Sorry, i missed the "type" attribute.

Comment: could you give me explanation ? why numeric character worked ? in test postman

Comment: not work code from you always forbidden request multiple checkbox

Comment: thank you worked but i remove JSON.stringify(data);

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am assuming you haven't used checkboxes as array input. You need to use array input for your checkboxes like this:

```
 var arr = $('input[name="available[]"]:checked').map(function () {
                data.push($(this).val());
            }).get();
```

also Change your HTML code to :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="available[]" class="checkbox" value="Some value here"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="available[]" class="checkbox" value="Some value here"/>
```

You can also change your jquery code to :

```
 var arr = $('.checkbox:checked').map(function () {
                data.push($(this).val());
            }).get();
```

Or if you are submitting form you can get form data as :

```
 var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
```

Comment: but in my local computer working my code then when migrate to server cannot work, ok thank you i will try it

Comment: could you give me explanation ? why numeric character worked ?  in test postman

Comment: Are you passing csrf token in post request? You have to pass csrf token in Post request.

Comment: just 403 error forbidden you don't have access permission

Comment: From postman you are passing data in Query Params i.e. in URL but from jquery you are passing data as form data.

Comment: not work code from you always forbidden request multiple checkbox

Comment: thank you worked but i remove JSON.stringify(data);